# Remove third party debug messages from output in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am using a third party library in a project and it spams the Output console with its own messages. I have absolutely no desire to see the messages when I'm debugging my code. Is there any way to tell VS to not display the outside libraries messages and only display mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot filter the output debug messages, but in general there is way to tell the libraries not to dump messages to the output debug window (compile time define / runtime call / outer configuration tool like netsh.exe).